# GIT remote push issues

Tags: eclipse, git, github

Hi i have a spring mvc application project developed in eclipse and retrieved from my private github repo and i seem to have issues pushing my changes into master remote.

Here is the error i get when i try to push to upstream using eclipse's git plugin

```
 https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git: https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack not found
```

any ideas?

I have committed my changes successfully into the local repository on my workstation but i am unable to push the new committed changes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried `http` instead of `https`?